# Convert a value in the json array into another using JOLT

Tags: jolt

I have this input

```
[
  {
    "date": "2020-01-01",
    "state_cd": "CA"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-01-03",
    "state_cd": "NY"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-01-05",
    "state_cd": "WA"
  }
]
```

and would like to convert state_cd to 1 if it's CA or 0 otherwise.

I tried the following spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "state_cd": {
          "CA": {
            "#1": "[].ca_ind"
          },
          "*": {
            "#0": "[].ca_ind"
          }
        },
        "*": "[&1].&0"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

but the state cd is one index skewed from what I supposed to like this.

```
[
  {
    "date" : "2020-01-01"
  },
  {
    "ca_ind" : "1",
    "date" : "2020-01-03"
  },
  {
    "ca_ind" : "0",
    "date" : "2020-01-05"
  },
  {
    "ca_ind" : "0"
  }
]
```

Could anyone help me how to address this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "date": "[&1].date",
        "state_cd": {
          "CA": {
            "#1": "[&3].ca_ind"
          },
          "*": {
            "#0": "[&3].ca_ind"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: K now I see what I need to change: so I needed to pass &3 into [].ca_ind. Here is the actual spec that I wanted to have:
`"CA": { "#1": "[&3].ca_ind"},`
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

K, Jagadesh gave me the idea what my actual spec should look like:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "state_cd": {
          "CA": {
            "#1": "[&3].ca_ind"
          },
          "*": {
            "#0": "[&3].ca_ind"
          }
        },
        "*": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Thanks!